# Selecting all child objects in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

This really should be easy, but I just can't work it out myself, the interface is not intuitive enough... :(

Let's say I have a `State` table, and I want to select all `Counties` from multiple `States`.  In SQL that would be:

```
select c.*
  from State s join County c on c.StateCode = s.StateCode
 where s.TimeZone = -5 -- or some other criteria
```

The above example is trivial enough to convert to Linq in a static context:

```
var q = MyDataContext.GetTable<County>().Where(c => c.State.TimeZone = -5);
```

But where it starts getting complicated is if I want a more context sensitive query, such as the following:

```
public static List<County> GetCountiesForStates(List<State> states) {
  // gotta do something to return all the counties for all these states
}
```

Now I could do something like this inside that method:

```
var q = MyDataContext.GetTable<County>().Where(c => states.Contains(c.State));
```

but IMO that is really inelegant, because (a) I have to get a static `MyDataContext` instead of using the implicit data context of the State objects and (b) you're working backwards, and if you start complicating the query further it gets even uglier.

Is there a way of starting the query with:

```
var q = states... // or "from s in states..."
```

Instinctively, I want to believe you can do this, but I haven't yet found the way...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var q = from c in countries
        from s in c.States
        where c.Property == Something
        select s;
```

This will give you an enumeration of all states within all countries. This translates into the following:

```
var q = countries.Where(x => c.Property == Something).SelectMany(c => c.States);
```

Comment: Just what I wanted - THANK YOU!

Comment: This answer is somewhat confusing, because it references "countries" while the OP is concerned with "counties". The hierarchy is therefore reversed.